# Keras custom masking layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am struggling with custom masking input from Flatten layer with tf.boolean_mask. Could you please give me a hint why no masking occurs producing (None, 1024) output? I will appreciate any help. 
Thank you :)

```
class InputReduction(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, mask_idx):
        super(InputReduction, self).__init__()
        self.mask_idx = mask_idx

    def call(self, inputs):
        mask = np.array([True for _ in range(inputs.shape[1])])
        for idx in self.mask_idx:
            mask[idx] = False
            
        print(mask)
        inputs = tf.boolean_mask(inputs, mask)
        print(inputs.shape)
        
        return inputs
```

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
    
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
    
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    InputReduction(mask_idx=[1,2,3]),
    keras.layers.Dense(512, activation = 'relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
])

model.summary()
```

My output:

input_reduction_5 (InputRedu (None, 1024)              0

Comment: Your code does not reproduce your issue. What is `model` in your example? It is never defined. See how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @gobrewers14 sorry, I pasted my model. It looks alike there is sthing wrong with shape.

Comment: You have a 1D tensor after Flatten, (Batchsize, Channels). You want to mask N elements of each sample, to be (Batchsize, N) (in your question, N=3 gathering axis=1,2, 3) .  Am I right?

Comment: @Watanabe.N yes I want to mask input of (Batchsize, N) with indexes from the array. For example: batch_size = 3, N = 5. input = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]], lets mask_idx = [1,3], so the output should be [[1,3,5], [6,8,10], [11,13,15]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use `tf.gather` instead of `tf.mask_boolean`. In all solutions, `inputs.shape` is expected to be [Batchsize, Channels].

### Solution 1:  `tf.mask(..., axis=1)`

```py
import tensorflow as tf

print('tf.__version__ =', tf.__version__)


class InputReduction(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, mask_idx):
        super(InputReduction, self).__init__()
        self.mask_idx = mask_idx

    def call(self, inputs):
        batchsize, channels = inputs.shape
        mask = tf.constant([True if i in self.mask_idx else False  for i in range(channels)], dtype=tf.bool)  # [C,]
        tf.print('mask =', mask)
        return tf.boolean_mask(inputs, mask, axis=1)  # mask from axis=1 to ignore batchsize axis

x = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])  # (3, 4)
print('x =', x)
y = InputReduction(mask_idx=[0, 2])(x)
print('y =', y)
```

Output

```
tf.__version__ = 2.4.1
x = tf.Tensor(
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12]], shape=(3, 4), dtype=int32)
mask = [1 0 1 0]
y = tf.Tensor(
[[ 1  3]
 [ 5  7]
 [ 9 11]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=int32)
```

### Solution 2: Match shapes of mask and inputs, then `tf.reshape` output

```py
import tensorflow as tf

print('tf.__version__ =', tf.__version__)


class InputReduction(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, mask_idx):
        super(InputReduction, self).__init__()
        self.mask_idx = mask_idx

    def call(self, inputs):
        batchsize, channels = inputs.shape
        mask = tf.constant([True if i in self.mask_idx else False  for i in range(channels)], dtype=tf.bool)  # [C,]
        mask = tf.stack((mask,) * batchsize, axis=0)
        tf.print('mask =', mask)
        outputs = tf.boolean_mask(inputs, mask)  # [Batchsize * N]
        return tf.reshape(outputs, (batchsize, -1))  # [Batchsize, N]

x = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])  # (3, 4)
print('x =', x)
y = InputReduction(mask_idx=[0, 2])(x)
print('y =', y)
```

Output

```
tf.__version__ = 2.4.1
x = tf.Tensor(
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12]], shape=(3, 4), dtype=int32)
mask = [[1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 1 0]]
y = tf.Tensor(
[[ 1  3]
 [ 5  7]
 [ 9 11]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=int32)
```

### Solution 3: `tf.gather` (Recommended)

No need of a mask.

```
import tensorflow as tf

print('tf.__version__ =', tf.__version__)


class InputReduction(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, mask_idx):
        super(InputReduction, self).__init__()
        self.mask_idx = mask_idx

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.gather(inputs, self.mask_idx, axis=1)

x = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])  # (3, 4)
print('x =', x)
y = InputReduction(mask_idx=[0, 2])(x)
print('y =', y)
```

Output

```
tf.__version__ = 2.4.1
x = tf.Tensor(
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12]], shape=(3, 4), dtype=int32)
y = tf.Tensor(
[[ 1  3]
 [ 5  7]
 [ 9 11]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=int32)
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solution 3 worked perfectly. I have tried Solution 1 before, but it doesn't work when your custom layer is followed by another layer.

Comment: Solution 1 works even when you add another layer. I confirmed by ```z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(y)
print('z=', z)```, ```z= tf.Tensor(
[[3.1496382]
 [5.236237 ]
 [7.322836 ]], shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32)```

Answer (score -1):

At the beginning you created an instance of your defined layer and passed a list:

```
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    InputReduction(mask_idx=[1,2,3]),  # <---
    keras.layers.Dense(512, activation = 'relu'),
```

In the constructor the list has been saved.

```
class InputReduction(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, mask_idx):
        super(InputReduction, self).__init__()
        self.mask_idx = mask_idx  # <---
```

In the call you iterated over this list of three numbers `[1, 2, 3]` and set the value to `False`:

```
    def call(self, inputs):
        mask = np.array([True for _ in range(inputs.shape[1])])
        for idx in self.mask_idx:  # <--- `[1, 2, 3]`
            mask[idx] = False
```

The result is ...

```
[True, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, ...]
```

And finally `tf.boolean_mask` shrinks the output:

```
tensor = [0, 1, 2, 3]  # 1-D example
mask = np.array([True, False, True, False])
tf.boolean_mask(tensor, mask)
# <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([0, 2], dtype=int32)>
```

Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask

Technically this should work, but it doesn't make sense to overwrite the inputs. So my question is: What do you want to do? What is your desired result of this custom layers? Is this the place right after a `Flatten` layer the right place?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand what I do. My question is how to mask elements of batch by index. Lets assume I have input (batch_size, N) and I would like to remove last element for each sample. Iit should be placed after Flatten layer, it is part of my reserach.

Comment: This isn't an answer. This should go into a comment section.

Comment: @Watanabe.N Until now it's not possible to quote multiple lines of code which is crucial to discuss and to keep the overview and simplicity. It's that simple.

Comment: I know. Even though an answer is an answer, not for keeping the overview and simplicity.